# Why multifiles uploader don't upload files?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, pdo, multifile-uploader

I've tried to code multiple files uploader with sorter by database on my website.. but if i upload some files, uploader send me notices..

```
Notice: Undefined index: media in /var/www/mediasorter/mediaupload.php on line 18
Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /var/www/mediasorter/mediaupload.php on line 18
Notice: Undefined index: media in /var/www/mediasorter/mediaupload.php on line 19
Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /var/www/mediasorter/mediaupload.php on line 19
Notice: Undefined index: media in /var/www/mediasorter/mediaupload.php on line 20
Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /var/www/mediasorter/mediaupload.php on line 20
Notice: Undefined index: media in /var/www/mediasorter/mediaupload.php on line 21
Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /var/www/mediasorter/mediaupload.php on line 21
Notice: Undefined index: media in /var/www/mediasorter/mediaupload.php on line 22
Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /var/www/mediasorter/mediaupload.php on line 22
Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in /var/www/mediasorter/mediaupload.php on line 23
Notice: Undefined variable: towritesql in /var/www/mediasorter/mediaupload.php on line 50
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '';'' at line 1 in...
```

```
<script>
function _(el){
    return document.getElementById(el);
}
function uploadFile(){
    var formdata = new FormData();

    var ins = _('media').files.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < ins; i++) {
        formdata.append("media[]", _('media').files[i]);
    }

    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
    ajax.open("POST", "mediaupload.php");
    ajax.send(formdata);
}
function progressHandler(event){
    _("loaded_n_total").innerHTML = "Uploaded "+event.loaded+" bytes of "+event.total;
    var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
    _("progressBar").value = Math.round(percent);
    _("status").innerHTML = Math.round(percent)+"% uploaded... please wait";
}
function completeHandler(event){
    _("status").innerHTML = event.target.responseText;
    _("progressBar").value = 0;
}
function errorHandler(event){
    _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Failed";
}
function abortHandler(event){
    _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Aborted";
}
</script>
```

```
    <form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="mediaupload.php" method="post">
      <input type="file" name="media[]" id="media" multiple><br>
      <input type="button" value="Upload File" onclick="uploadFile()">
        <input type="submit" value="manual">
      <progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100" style="width:300px;"></progress>
      <h3 id="status"></h3>
      <p id="loaded_n_total"></p>
    </form>
```

and upload php code:

```
<?php
require 'DBConnection.php';

function generateRandomString($length = 10)
{
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0;$i < $length;$i++)
    {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1) ];
    }
    return $randomString;
}

$namestodb = array();
$dir = "./media/";
$name_array = $_FILES['media']['name'];
$tmp_name_array = $_FILES['media']['tmp_name'];
$type_array = $_FILES['media']['type'];
$size_array = $_FILES['media']['size'];
$error_array = $_FILES['media']['error'];
for ($i = 0;$i < count($tmp_name_array);$i++)
{
    $randomname = generateRandomString(10);
    $tempfilename = explode(".", $name_array[$i]);
    $newfilename = $randomname . '.' . end($tempfilename);
    if ($type_array[$i] == "video/mp4")
    {
        $mediatype = "video";
    }
    else
    {
        $mediatype = "image";
    }
    if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array[$i], $dir.$newfilename))
    {
        echo $newfilename." nahrávání dokončeno<br>";
        array_push($namestodb, '(NULL, "No name", "'.$newfilename.'", NULL, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, "", "' . $mediatype . '", "", "", "0", "local", NULL, NULL)');
    }
    else
    {
        echo "move_uploaded_file function failed for " . $name_array[$i] . "<br>";
    }
}
foreach ($namestodb as $name)
{
    $towritesql .= $name . ',';
}
$towritesql = substr($towritesql, 0, -1) . ';';
$conn = new DBConnection;
$conn->insertmedia($towritesql);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

there is nothing wrong with your code. What I can understand from the error is that the you tried to Upload the file/s without selecting any file/s.

**Try adding a if/else condition to check if the upload array is empty or not.**

I have tried your code it is working exactly how it should work.

Comment: I've tried to test it on windows xampp server and upload works (but not writing in database..), but i want this operate on linux server and error mean that upload array is empty...maybe my server haven't done some module?? or it is error by PHP 7.4??